# calculate the rate under the same in using R

Tags: r, rate

I have a question to calculate the rate under the same id numbers.
Here is the sample dataset d:

```
id answer
1   1
1   0
1   0
1   1
1   1
1   1
1   0
2   0
2   0
2   0
3   1
3   0
```

The ideal output is

```
id  rate          freq
1   4/7 (=0.5714)  7
2   0              3
3   1/2 (=0.5)     2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(rate= mean(answer), freq=.N) ,id]
#   id      rate freq
#1:  1 0.5714286    7
#2:  2 0.0000000    3
#3:  3 0.5000000    2
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(rate=mean(answer), freq=n())
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), answer = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L)), .Names = c("id", "answer"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use don't use `mean` in the dplyr approach?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  First I coded it as `sum()/n()` as the `mean` didn't click for me by looking at the expected output.  Then, I realized that `mean` works and forgot to change it for the `dplyr`

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, you can use `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(answer~id, function(x) c(rate=mean(x), freq=length(x)), data=df1)
  id answer.rate answer.freq
1  1   0.5714286   7.0000000
2  2   0.0000000   3.0000000
3  3   0.5000000   2.0000000
```

Comment: Depending on what you want as output you may want to add this statement after the `aggregate` statement where `ag` is the output of the `aggregate` statement:   `with(ag, data.frame(id, answer))`